# How can I setup a container with container name as computer name?

Tags: docker, docker-container

For example, when I login to my container

```
docker exec -it vuejs_ci bash  
root@3dc77c3403c8:/#
```

It is using container ID `3dc77c3403c8` as computer name. How can I make it `root@container_name` when I setup my container?

Comment: `docker run -it --hostname container_name --name container_name ubuntu bash` now the container name and hostname will be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible from the `docker exec` command, but with the `docker run` command, you can pass a `--hostname <name>` to set your container's host name.

```
$ docker run -it --hostname container_name ubuntu:18.04 bash
root@container_name:/#
root@container_name:/# echo $HOSTNAME
container_name
root@container_name:/# hostname
container_name
```

By default, containers use their container ID for their hostname. From https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname:

> In the same way, a container’s hostname defaults to be the container’s
>   ID in Docker. You can override the hostname using --hostname.